# is there a visit method to get xml tags as nodes, from velocity template

Tags: velocity

I have a velocity template that needs to be parsed and validated.

```
#foreach ($array_item in ${some_array})
    <somthing attribute1="attri1" attribute2="${array_item.meth1}"    

      attribute3="${array_item.meth2}" attribute4="${array_item.meth3}">
        some text
   </something>
#end
```

I am using org.apache.velocity.runtime.visitor.BaseVisitor to parse this.
I am bale to get the velocity directives, String literals, reference, using the respective visitor methods.
I need to get the xml tag out of this template. Is there a visitor that can
be used to get XML tags separated out? or is  there a visitor that can give me each line as a node?

Answer (score 0):

Velocity is format-agnostic, that means it doesn't know if the output will be plain text, xml, html or whatever. A VTL reference could contain xml tags, or just tag starts, etc... so a template itself is not supposed at all to be valid XML.
If you know your templates are valid XML, then you could parse them directly using an XML parser, and recognize VTL elements inside afterwards. Or only parse the generated result, if applicable. But we'd need some insight on your goal...